# What is this chrome-<long-string-of-characters>-Default.desktop file?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

Is chrome-kajebgjangihfbkjfejcanhanjmmbcfd-Default.desktop malware?

[image: chrome-weird.desktop]

Comment: That would be a shortcut to one of the Google Chrome webapps like Docs or Sheets etc.  You can always cat the file to show you what it is.  `cat chrome-kajebgjangihfbkjfejcanhanjmmbcfd-Default.desktop`

Comment: @Terrance This is what I got. So, safe?

#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Password Manager
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=kajebgjangihfbkjfejcanhanjmmbcfd
Icon=chrome-kajebgjangihfbkjfejcanhanjmmbcfd-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_kajebgjangihfbkjfejcanhanjmmbcfd

Comment: Yes, it's shortcut to Chrome APP "password manager", same what you see if you enter to URL bar `chrome://password-manager/passwords`.

Comment: Phew! I have been a little paranoid since my phone got hacked. Thanks guys!

Comment: However, I don't recall the password manager as being an app.  Feel free to delete the file.  The apps that Google has can be found at https://workspace.google.com/features/

Comment: Just deleted. Off topic. Do you guys have any recommendation on how to keep my ubuntu secure? Or is there a way to check if any boot and startup files have been modified? Any resources would be helpful.

Comment: There is a lot of information out there on how to harden or secure your OS installation.  One thing to remember that if you encrypt your drive as a means of protection, this does not help when you are browsing online.  Hard drive encryption is good for local security like someone stealing your computer, etc.  One place to start might be https://linuxsecurity.com/features/the-most-important-things-you-can-do-to-quickly-secure-ubuntu-linux but if you look out there, you can find lots of good info.

Answer (score 2):

Per comments, that is a link to a Chrome App that is a password manager.  Typically it doesn't get put onto your desktop for execution that way though.

You can safely delete that file, and it's not Malware.